# Clustering algorithms: K-means, Fuzzy C-means, and Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: clustering, references

I am writing my thesis and my field of study is sparse representations. I'd like to add a section on clustering algorithms such as K-means, Fuzzy C-means and Singular Value Decomposition to my thesis and I am looking for some popular books on the subject. I am familiar with the concept but I'd like to get an idea of how it should be explained in a scientific manner.

Comment: SVD itself isn't a clustering algorithm at all. Do you mean by it some clustering algo using svd (there exist some)? which one then? Also, `scientific manner` - a bit broad term.

Comment: @ttnphns In that case I can remove SVD from the list. I need a quick review with the highlight of important points such as the role of centroids and the chosen k as the number of cluster centers and such.

Answer (score 1):

From a statistician's perspective:

> Cluster Analysis, 5th Edition
>
> Brian S. Everitt, Sabine Landau, Morven Leese, Daniel Stahl

http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002266.html

> Finding Groups in Data: An Introduction to Cluster Analysis

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470316801

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at:

> Introduction to Machine Learning, 3rd Edition, Ethem Alpaydin, MIT Press

It's a very accessible and well-written book. You will find particularly useful the Chapter 7, which is specifically about clustering.